# I need to create a powershell script to trigger a specific windows task daily on a specific interval of time for a particular duration

Tags: powershell

I need to create a powershell script to trigger a specific windows task daily on a specific interval of time for a particular duration.

My scenario is like this task needs to be trigger everyday on a half an hour interval from 5 am to 5 pm. I tried with the New-JobTrigger  options, but I dont see an repetation option.

I am using powershell version 5.1

Answer (score 0):

Try heading towards a scheduled task.
- Write your powershell script.
- Create a scheduled task that runs it whenever you want with a specified time range.